# Foundation memory management for properties

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, core-foundation

For a project not using ARC, assuming I have a property on my class:

```
@property (assign) CGPathRef pathRef;
```

And I have a method updating this Path reference at some point, for example:

```
UIBezierPath *bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:rect];
self.pathRef = CGPathCreateCopy(bezierPath.CGPath);
```

In my dealloc, I am doing as follows:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    CGPathRelease(self.pathRef);
    self.pathRef = nil;

    [super dealloc];
}
```

When running the static analyser I'm getting this Memory advice for the line where I am using `CGPathRelease`:

> Incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object that is not
>   owned at this point by the caller.

I thought I was onto something here https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1565/_index.html but it seems this is explaining how to hand off foundation objects to the Core Animation APIs.

Can anyone advise on this, how can I manage this Foundation object without static analyser warning?

Answer (score 3):

You don't own the return value of a property accessor. Use the instance variable instead.

```
CGPathRelease(_pathRef);
```

Alternatively (and preferably), you can implement the accessor methods yourself and include the memory management.

```
- (void)setPathRef:(CGPathRef)val
{
    if (_pathRef)
    {
        CGPathRelease(_pathRef);
        _pathRef = NULL;
    }
    if (val)
    {
         _pathRef = CGPathCreateCopy(val);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Regarding your first solution, in addition to `CGPathRelease(_pathRef)` in `dealloc`, you would obviously also use the ivar for assignment, too, such a `_pathRef = CGPathCreateCopy(bezierPath.CGPath);`. That eliminates the other static analyzer warning.

Comment: Regarding your custom setter solution, while that enjoys a certain elegance (a) you will get a warning with this `setPathRef` unless you define the property to be `nonatomic`; and (b) it's vaguely discomfiting to have an `assign` property that is actually engaging in `retain`-like behavior (though, you obviously cannot use `retain` with non-objects), so I'd advise a comment at the property declaration to make this clear.

Comment: Hi, @Rob, could you please explain why he will get a warning if the property is defined as `atomic`? Furthermore, what part of the code shows that it is engaging in `retain`-like behavior though it is `assign`? Thanks.

Comment: @Unheilig The `atomic` issue stems from the fact that this is a synchronization mechanism. But the synthesized getter can't possibly coordinate the atomic locking with a custom setter because it has no way of knowing what precisely that custom setter is doing.

Comment: @Unheilig Regarding the `retain`-like behavior, perhaps I should have said a `copy`-like behavior, but the fundamental issue is the same. You have a setter which is releasing the old value and creating a copy with a +1 retain count. That's not `assign` memory semantics. That's `copy` memory semantics. One should generally have the declaration of the property memory semantics that reflects the actual behavior of the setter.

Answer (score 2):

The other obvious solution in this scenario is to just use the `UIBezierPath` object, which gets you out of the weeds of `CGPathRef` create/release logic and bypasses this static analyzer idiosyncrasy. Thus, define a property:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIBezierPath *bezierPath;
```

And then, when you want to set it:

```
UIBezierPath *bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:rect];
self.bezierPath = bezierPath;
```

And when you need the `CGPath`, just grab it from the `UIBezierPath`, e.g.:

```
CGContextAddPath(context, self.bezierPath.CGPath);
```

And then in `dealloc`, you can just `release` it:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [_bezierPath release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

That way, you can enjoy the simplicity of the object memory semantics, can use some of the nice convenience methods of `UIBezierPath`, can use other techniques that aren't readily available for Core Foundation types (e.g. `autorelease`), but you still get the `CGPath` for it whenever you need it.

There are times you have to employ one of the techniques advised by Darren (+1), notably when there isn't some logical object corresponding to the Core Foundation type, but in this `CGPathRef` example, I generally use `UIBezierPath` object instead. Given that you're starting with a `UIBezierPath` object already, it's even more compelling.